# Highlight row in Dataframe and send automate email with condition

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, automation, teradata

There are 2 requests I need for this assignment:

1. I need to send out automate email to teammate ONLY when there is new purchase available
2. I want to highlight the row (in yellow) that represents the new purchases, so my teammate can easy to see them right away.

I am using teradata_simba Kernal for a mysql table. My Purchase table contain 3 column:
buyer_id - the buyer Id who purchase the products,
transaction_id - the txn id associate with the purchase,
Purchase_date - the timestamp of the purchase date

[image: Click for Purchase Sample Table]

I need to notify my teammates using email whenever there is new purchase. The Python code I am using to send automate email is:

Data = %teradata_simba select * from Purchase order by Purchase_date desc

df = Data.DataFrame()

df.to_excel('Purchase_activity.xlsx', index=False)

%sendmail -to "jasonchen@yahoo.com" -res Data

The email is automatically sent out everyday. However, not everyday will have a new purchase. I only want to send out the email whenever there is a new purchase available. For the table example, I only want python to send out email on 5/1, 5/12 and 5/27. I think I can add a logic to compare the previous days to the current day, but I am not sure how. Please help.

Also, I want to highlight the row (in yellow) that represents the new purchases, so my teammate can easy to see right away.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a daily feed you can send only the records that fall on the previous date

```
select * from Purchase Where Purchase_date= Current_Date()-1
```